# Nexus 5x connected external HDMI/DP - how?

Tags: external-display, nexus-5x

I want to connect my LG Nexus 5x to an external HDMI or Display Port (in mirror or extended desktop mode).

Is it possible? Which connectors/cables required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work with slimport!  The Nexus 5x has a USB type c port.  Also google has stated that the 5X will not work with USB type c to HDMI adapters. The only way currently to get the video signal from the 5X or 6P is to use screen mirroring with a supported device (chromecast or Nexus player).

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can try connecting it using slimport adapter
but as I mentioned before I'm not sure

Comment: Chromecast is working fine. The only bad thing regarding chromecasting it strongly drains battery and loads GPU/CPU for screen encoding to stream.